# How to add a column (interger type) to a column that is a date? Pyspark/ Spark dataframe?

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, azure-databricks

I have a dataframe with the following details: (first df in image)

I want to be able to add new rows to to df that calculate the column next_apt + days with the new timestamp that it was run. So I want it to look like this:

the other columns should be left as it it. just add the next next_apt with the newer timestamp that it was calculated and append the rows to the same df.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Use [date_add](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/functions.html#date_add-org.apache.spark.sql.Column-org.apache.spark.sql.Column-) and cast it to timestamp

This should work:

```
df1.withColumn("newDateWithTimestamp", F.date_add(F.col("next_apt"), F.col("days")).cast("timestamp")).show()
```

Input

[image: Input]

Output
[image: Output]